Packages libssl, libc, libcrypto error installing MongoDB on CentOS
I've tried to install MongoDB 7.0 on my instance, but got a following error:

Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.29)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libssl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libcrypto.so.3(OPENSSL_3.0.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libssl.so.3(OPENSSL_3.0.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-database-tools-100.9.4-1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libcrypto.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.29)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libssl.so.3(OPENSSL_3.0.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libssl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libcrypto.so.3(OPENSSL_3.0.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-mongos-7.0.11-1.el9.x86_64 (mongodb-org-7.0)
Requires: libcrypto.so.3()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Searching over internet did not gave any results. Can someone say how to solve it?
here is version:
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

Which repository has been added for this environment?
